# Execute a function every x minutes

Tags: wordpress, timer

In WordPress, and without additional tools, how can I *execute a function every x minutes*?

I want to import new posts from another website programmaticaly (namely videos from a YouTube account), and I don't want to execute all the required checks on every pageload.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know WordPress that well, or how you are importing the new posts.  But could you combine an HTML  ( refresh ), and a javascript onRefresh() function?